# Resolve URL from database query in ASP.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

When I go to get my images from my database in ASP.net and it loads in to the boundfield all I see is 
this

```
     ~\Images\Husqvarna-HU700L.jpg 
or
     ~\Images\Husqvarna-95600L.jpg
```

instead of the image because it's not in the root.

My site is not going to be in the root directory and I need to figure out how to resolve the url to an absolute. Would it be a link or some C# method?

Comment: I guess how would I ResolveURL for multiple files like that whenever the query gets called?

Comment: You do it in your .NET controls which display images, as it has nothing to do with the query or database.

Comment: Would I do that with an ItemTemplate? Sorry I am new to this.

Comment: You likely have somewhere in your ItemTemplate where you bind the image to an image control. There you can use ResolveUrl